# High Availability for Bluemix Secure Gateway Docker Client

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Architecting a solution on Bluemix that will use the Secure Gateway service to connect to on-premise resources. 
Trying to understand how to approach achieving a production high availability configuration for the Secure Gateway Client which runs inside a Docker contained provided by Bluemix.

How are others approaching HA for the SG Client?

Comment: Hello... You are unlikely to get the answers if you are not specific. Please visit the help center and see the guidelines for asking a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker does support an auto-start functionality, but there is no built in support within Secure Gateway currently to take advantage of that.  Our next release (1.3.0) will support native installers for Linux (Ubuntu, RHEL and SLES), which will be out last week this month.  Once out, you could use the native installer, setup the auto-start facility and control your client using native upstart or systemD capabilities.